# iMacro text field Inputting issue

Tags: imacros

hopefully you can help me. This is my attempt at using a macro to add text into a text field on a website.​

This is my current iMacro code, which opens the text box (by clicking a couple of buttons) however doesn't activate the text box nor add any text into it:

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=https://datatron.l2inc.com/#resources?selected=brandTab5229&brands=5229
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=TXT:Create<SP>New<SP>Resources<SP>for<SP>Brand
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=ID:add-urls
PROMPT "Please enter something:" !VAR1

TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA ATTR=CLASS:form-control CONTENT={{!VAR1}}
```

The last lines are my attempt adding my own text (VAR1) into the textbox. The relevant html code (created by javascript) simply reads as this:

```
​<textarea class="form-control urls-textarea" rows="10" placeholder="irrelevant placeholder text"></textarea>
```

Do you know where I am going wrong??

Best regards

Roman

Answer (score 0):

Try to record your manual typing wlth 'Experimental event recording mode'.

Taking into account the html code you provided, the event command may look like:

```
EVENTS TYPE=KEYPRESS SELECTOR="textarea[class='form-control urls-textarea']" CHARS={{!VAR1}}
```